# Different versions of $(\mathbb{Z}^{*}_{2^k}, \cdot)$

Tags: linear-algebra, modular-arithmetic, congruence-relations

I had to prove two statments, which I was supposed to use to prove two other ones:

1. For $k \geq 3, \:$ $\:5^{2^{k-3}} \equiv 1 \: \mod 2^{k-1}$, but $5^{2^{k-3}} \not\equiv 1 \mod 2^k$
2. For $k \geq 3, \:$ $\: (-1)^i5^j \equiv  (-1)^m5^n \mod2^k \Rightarrow (-1)^i \equiv (-1)^m \mod4$

I have **PROVED** both of them, but I have to use them for the following two:

For $(\mathbb{Z}^{*}_{2^k}, \cdot)$ with $k \geq 3:$

1. ord $(\bar{5}) = 2^{k-2}$
2. $\mathbb{Z}^{*}_{2^k} = \{ (\bar{-1})^{i}\bar{5}^j | i\in\{0,1\}, 0\leq j \leq 2^{2k-2}\}=\left \langle \bar{-1}, \bar{5} \right \rangle$

I would appreciate any kind of help!

Comment: What have you tried?  The first statement, for example, is just a restatement of one of the other points.

Comment: @lulu So for the first one, I was just thinking about changing variables. For example, if we state $k= j+1$, then we get actually the one we need? But do I have to show anything for minimality of $k$ or that is enough?

Comment: You have already shown the minimality, that's part of your first claim.

Comment: Great! But the second claim I really don't know how to start.

Comment: Well, try.  Is $-1$ in the subgroup generated by $5$?

Comment: Okay, I will try it, thank you for your hints. Could you just explain to me how the first claim shows the minimality. Intuitivly, I can understand I somehow but unfortunately I cannot formulate it mathematicaly.

Comment: Again, try.  You need to show some effort here. To get you started, first let $g$ be the order of $5\pmod {2^k}$.  Show that $g\,|\,2^{k-2}$

Comment: Okay, so I am supposed to prove that there is no such $m$ less than $2^{k-2}$, so that $5^m=1 \mod 2^k$ 
If there was such $m$, then it would have to mean that $m|2^{k-2}$. My question is, how does the second part of the first claim help me to prove that there is no such $m$?

Comment: I gave you a hint already.  Let $g$ be the order of $5\pmod {2^k}$.  Show that $g\,|\,2^{k-2}$.

Comment: I already have that fact proven in a theorem, so I can just use it. g |$ 2^{k-2}$ is a consequence of g being the order of 5. But I am supposed to show that there is no such g. I understand that g can be 2, 2^2, 2^3, ..., 2^(k-3). How I am I supposed to show that none of these can be order of 5?

Comment: Of course there is such a $g$, namely $2^{k-2}$. itself.  Now show that any other divisor of $2^{k-2}$ would have to be a divisor of $2^{k-3}$.